# How to Deploy a mobile web app ( html5+jQuery Mobile) on My Own PC in a Local Area Network

Tags: spring-boot, web-applications

I'm new to mobile web app development. I'm trying to complete a mobile web app project in my office, and come to ask how to start.

There is a Local Area Network(LAN) in our office. In my hypothesis, I will build a mobile web app using html5+jQuery Mobile for all my colleagues (about 50 people) in the office. And I'm using C++ Qt framework to build the backend server, which will handle the backend logic, send data to and get data from the web app running on several devices. The .html, .css and other files that defining the web app should be deployed only on the server PC.

My question is:

(1) How can my colleagues get access to these .html and .css files, and open them on their mobile phones or computers by just typing some URL (related to the IP address of my PC in the LAN) into their browser? Of course, their devices are also in this LAN as my PC, namely the server.

(2) And is there any tutorials, guidebook or blogs that may help with this issue?

This is just a prototype project for a demon in the office. So it is only required to work in such a small range. All the communication is supposed to be finished by HTTP.

Much appreciation!

Comment: Any server you run on your computer should be accessable to others on the LAN.  They simply need your IP address or your machine name resolution on the network.  For instance if your network were something like "internal.mycompany.net" and your machine name is "PC0045W" or something, you should be able to potentially access the pc with "http://PC0045W.internal.mycompany.net".  In any case, you just have to figure out which server you want to run and figure out your preferred method of sharing the ip.  But both of those are very broad issues.

Comment: Depending on what you want to code in, some languages have servers you can include automatically.  For instance, npm/nodejs has the option to include the "serve" package which can serve up static files.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve  I use this option for testing some of my things locally and it works fine. (example. https://github.com/taplar/webpack-vue-serviceworker)

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Additional information is that,  I'd like to use C++ and Qt frame work to implement this server on windows. And I hope that the web app can interact (request data and get response) with the server by HTTP. I understand that the HTTP communication can be handled by the API offered by Qt and the jQuery. But how can my colleagues get the html and css files on my PC when they have accessed my PC in the LAN? Is there any tutorials or guidebooks for this? Much Thanks!

Comment: You may want to tag your question with C++ and Qt then, to get some additional eyes on this question related to those topics.  @WeilyBrown

Comment: Much appreciation for your help! I've searched some resources and found there are lots of things to learn. I think spring-boot may be a more suitable structure for beginners like me and post a simple tutorial below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched some tutorials online these days and found something useful for web-dev beginners like me.

Some web application frameworks are helpful, in which spring-boot seems to be a simple one for beginners like me to use. The following tutorial,

https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-springboot-angularjs-bootstrap-springdata-j

provides a quite clear spring-boot web-app structure, with Java-implemented backend and ccs+js+html front-end.  I think it's a good demo project for beginner to learn about spring-boot and deeper web-app developing skills.